# Multiple functions in Spring Cloud Function on AWS lambda

Tags: spring, lambda, spring-cloud-function

I have a Spring Cloud Function application with two functions:

```
@Component
public class MyFunctionOne implements Function<Object, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(Object o) {
        return true;
    }
}

@Component
public class MyFunctionTwo implements Function<Object, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(Object o) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have both `spring-cloud-starter-function-web` and `spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws` in my project dependencies.

I would like to call both `MyFunctionOne` and `MyFunctionTwo` separately.

I can achieve this running locally in two ways. I can do this either calling function directly (since I am using `spring-cloud-starter-function-web`) by calling localhost:8080/myFunctionOne. Or I can use the [Function Routing](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_routing) functionality by calling localhost:8080/functionRouter and supplying `myFunctionOne` in `spring.cloud.function.definition` http header. This works fine and I can both trigger `MyFunctionOne` and `MyFunctionTwo` separately.

I have deployed the module to AWS Lambda. How do I supply `spring.cloud.function.definition` dynamically? According to [documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/adapters/aws-intro.adoc#user-content-aws-request-handlers) I can use `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker` as a AWS Lambda handler. Or, alternatively I can define my own `SpringBootStreamHandler`. However, it seems that it is not possible to define `spring.cloud.function.definition` dynamically.

Is there a way to choose a function in Spring Cloud Function deployed to AWS lambda?

Answer (score 2):

So, we have a bit of an issue with routing on AWS and it is being fixed as we speak. You can follow this issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/698.

In any event, we'll have a new release early next week (3.1.3-RELEASE) which will include the fixes, samples and docs to address the issue you're describing